# Is a subset of the real n-dimensional space still in the Borel sigma algebra?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

1. If we have a set ${A}\subset{\mathbb{R}^n}$, then is the set ${A}$ a member of the Borel ${\sigma}$-algebra ${\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^n)}$?
2. Suppose ${\mathcal{O}^n}$ is the topology of ${\mathbb{R}^n}$, why ${A}\cap{\mathcal{O}^n}\subset{A}\cap{\sigma(\mathcal{O}^n)}$ holds?

Thanks for help!

Comment: (1) There are [[[some sets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel_set#Non-Borel_sets)]] which are not Borel.

Comment: (2) holds because every element $U\in\mathcal{O}^n$ is an element of $\sigma(\mathcal{O}^n)$ by definition. Therefore $A\cap U\in A\cap\sigma(\mathcal{O}^n)$.

Comment: (2) does not make sense . I think what you mean is $\{A\cap B: B\in O^n\}$ and $\{A\cap C:C\in \sigma(O^n)\}.$

Comment: A fundamental result of Cantor is that for any set $S$ there is no bijection from $P(S)$ to $S,$ where $P(S)$ is the set of all subsets of $S.$ ($\;P$ is for Power. $P(S)$ is called the Power Set of $S$.)  There is a bijection from $\sigma(O^n)$ to $\Bbb R$ and there is a bijection from $P(\Bbb R^n)$ to $P(\Bbb R)$ but no bijection from $P(\Bbb R)$ to $\Bbb R.$ Therefore $\sigma(O^n)\ne P(\Bbb R^n).$